# Find the dot that appears in the greatest number of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, pseudocode, rectangles

I've been trying to find an Algorithm for several days for this issue , with no success :

I got 2 lists - one containing points ( (x,y) ) and the other containing rectangles (each has two points - bottom left corner + upward right corner).

**The rectangles are parallel to the axis(to the x and y axis)**

I have to return the point which is inside the most number of rectangles in 
Θ(nlog(n)).

So given the running time needed .. i could sort both arrays however i like.. but still i don't seem to find a way to solve this in less then Θ(n^2).

Appreciate your Tips and Help.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Where does the restriction **Θ(nlog(n))** come from?

Comment: What is `n`? The number of points or number of rectangles?

Comment: @DAle the number of the points and the rectangles is the same - n.

Comment: @MrSmith42 its a question i've collected somewhere through the net.. trying to improve my algorithm solving skills.. but can't seem to figure this one out so far..

Comment: Duplicate just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722454/the-most-relevant-point-in-xy-dimension

Answer (score 2):

Approach with ready-to-use R-tree implementation, as LmTinyToon wrote, it simpler.

Otherwise you can use sweep line approach:

Sort point by X-coordinate and rectangles by left edge and by right edge.

Sweep with vertical line.

Insert active rectangles into interval tree when left edge is met and remove them when right edge is met.

Check every point against interval tree

Answer (score 1):

I advise to see at R-trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). It will allow to group rectangles. Then you can make point location queries. Hope it will help